# Media query keeps applying at a viewport size where it shouldn’t

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a question concerning media queries to make your website more responsive.

It seems the website developer mode does not recognize the width properly:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 1274px) {
        height: 290px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 892px) {
        height: 250px;
    }

    text-transform: uppercase;
    & .full-name {
        font-size: 5rem;
        position: absolute;
    }
    & .job-name {
        padding: 6rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

When I scale down to a phone size with the range of 300px - 450px width, it still shows that the page is using the min-width for 892px, and has 100px crossed out.

Is there a better way to master media queries?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does using a different browser, or resizing the window manually, make it work as expected?

Comment: Are you using `sass` to compile your css?

Comment: I am using sass to compile! And I've tried on Edge & Chrome only

Comment: (Also, check the value of `window.innerWidth` in the JavaScript console to make sure there isn’t any zoom in effect.)

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport"...` in head section of your html?

Comment: @Morpheus No, should there be one?

Comment: Yes, if you want your media queries to work :)

Comment: @Morpheus Wow, I didn't know you needed that. I'll try it when I get the chance!

Comment: (You don’t need it for media queries to work, but you do need it for mobile browsers – including the in-browser mobile view – not to pretend to have a desktop-like viewport.)